# Gravatar image in my static webite

Tags: javascript, image-processing, gravatar

I need to import current gravatar image in my website so that no matter when they change it in the gravatar it will automatically change it in my website...

I dont want php, python nor any such... I just need a simple link.. or may be simple javascript.. that I could include in the IMG tag that would automatically change the picture when they change in gravatar and in my website.

I tried to use php script but I dont want to use php.

I need a simple solution for a site ending with .html page.

Comment: https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/ has full instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Check this jQuery library 
https://github.com/zachleat/jQuery-Gravatar

And it's demo here http://www.zachleat.com/javascript/gravatar/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The extremely simple API is described here: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

1. Take user email address.
2. [Hash it.](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/)
3. Use `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{hash}`.

(All I did was Google "Gravatar API." It wouldn't have been hard to do that yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to create an MD5 Hash of the email address.  You can use [Crypto-JS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) for this.  Note, you'll want to convert the email address to all lowercase and trim any spaces off.

Next, you'll have to create an image using the [proper URL](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/).  Basically, the format for this is `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<Hash>` where `<Hash>` is the hash you just created.

This appears to work, at least for my email address:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script>
   var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("user3259486@gmail.com");
   document.write('<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hash + '" />');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9JZKZ/1/)